# Bounding modulus of complex functions if argument is large enough

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = \frac{ z^2}{(z^2 + a^2)^2} $ where $a > 0$. $|z| \geq R $ for $R$ large enough so that $z = ai $ lies inside $|z| = R $, can we bound $|f(z)| $ by a $\frac{M}{R^k}$ where $M$ is constant and $k > 1$ ??  What I got:
We know $|z^2 + a^2| \geq |z|^2 - |a|^2 $ and so

$$ |f(z)| \leq \frac{ |z|^2}{(|z|^2-|a|^2)^2} \leq \frac{ R^2}{((R^2-|a|^2)^2} = \frac{ R^2}{R^4 - 2 R^2 |a|^2 + |a|^4}$$

Is this bound good enough??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get something more transparent: Assume that $|z| = R \ge 2|a|$. Then
$$
|f(z)| \leq \frac{ |z|^2}{(|z|^2-|a|^2)^2} \leq \frac{R^2}{(R^2-\frac12 R^2)^2} = \frac{4}{R^2}.
$$

Comment: why can u assume $|z| \geq 2 |a|$ ??

Comment: I'm guessing you want this to estimate an integral, and you only require a bound for large values of $|z|$.